# QGIS 3.22 dialogs sometimes adding extra backslashes to commands resulting in errors

Tags: raster, gdal, qgis-3

Fairly frequently when I try to run raster commands in QGIS 3.22 (and earlier versions of Q3), I can't get the command to run because it appears that the GDAL command adds extra "".   For example in this instance I'm trying to look at raster information and this is what I see.  Where there should be "\" it puts "\\".  It sure would be nice to understand how to get around this problem easily or avoid it in the first place.

GDAL command:

```
gdalinfo "\\\\Allstate\\Files\\2010\\10144.01 East Locust\\Floodplain\\COE Feasibility Study HEC RAS Model\\HEC-RAS\\Terrain\\2018_10_18_ExistingConditions(FWOP_Year0)\\Existing Conditions.combined_export.tif"
```

GDAL command output:

```
ERROR 4: \\\\Allstate\\Files\\2010\\10144.01 East Locust\\Floodplain\\COE Feasibility Study HEC RAS Model\\HEC-RAS\\Terrain\\2018_10_18_ExistingConditions(FWOP_Year0)\\Existing Conditions.combined_export.tif: No such file or directory 
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '\\\\Allstate\\Files\\2010\\10144.01 East Locust\\Floodplain\\COE Feasibility Study HEC RAS Model\\HEC-RAS\\Terrain\\2018_10_18_ExistingConditions(FWOP_Year0)\\Existing Conditions.combined_export.tif'.
Process returned error code 1
```